# Does rtabmap_ros accepts IMU fusion?

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to fuse IMU data with vision while mapping with rtabmap_ros, I need to know if the algorithms actually accepts IMU fusion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299286/does-rtabmap_ros-accepts-imu-fusion?/) by [saratoonsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/36779/saratoonsi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The algorithm accepts any kind of odometry, so yes if you generate an odometry from fusion of IMU and vision, you can feed it to rtabmap. Just make sure that the twist covariance matrix in the generated odometry message makes sense (maybe around 10^-4 order for diagonal values) so that you don't have problems with bad graph optimization afterward in rtabmap.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saratoonsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/36779/saratoonsi/) on 2018-08-09**:
Thanks :) .